# Finding stable, unstable manifold and conjugacy homeomorphism

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems

This question is from Elaydi's Discrete Chaos, page 228:
Let $f: R^{2} \rightarrow R^{2} $ be given by $f(x,y)= (\frac{x}{2}, 2y- \frac{15}{8} x^{3}) $.

a) Show that the origin is a saddle point of $Df(0)$  (I have done that part).

b) Find the stable and unstable manifold $W^{s}(0)$ and $W^{u}(0)$

c) Find the conjugacy homeomorphism between $f$ and $Df(0)$.

d) Identify the heteroclinic points of $f$.

I haven't found similar examples, so I don't know how to do parts b), c) and d). Can someone do any of these parts and explain how to find stable and unstable manifold in general? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clearly the unstable manifold is the vertical axis. What did you try for the rest?

Comment: I found eigenvectors: (1,0) and (0,1). Stable and unstable manifolds are in direction of these vectors, so can we say that stable manifold is: $X(n)= (1/2)^n(0,1)$ and unstable manifold is $X(n)= 2^n (1,0) $  (x- and y-axis)?

Comment: Hum, no. Sorry, but it is apparent from your comment that you don't know the definition of a stable/unstable manifold. Without it you cannot solve the exercise. I strongly suggest that you first have a look at the theory.